# JSoup - Number of Table Rows per Table Body

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the following html table which i am trying to parse using JSoup.

I am parsing it as follows;

```
Elements table = document.select("table[class=MsoNormalTable]");
Elements tbody = table.select("tbody");
Elements tr = tbody.select("tr");
Elements td = tr.select("td");
Elements tableHeaders = td.select("p[class=MsoNormal]");
```

How am I able to find out, per table body how many table rows there are?

```
    <p class="MsoNormal"><b><u><span lang="EN-US">â‚¬ SUPR:</span></u></b></p>
    <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="585" style="width:438.45pt; margin-left:-1.05pt; border-collapse:collapse">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Available on TW</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="60" style="width:44.65pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Ticker</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="85" style="width:64.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Coupon</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="110" style="width:82.7pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Maturity Date
                        </span></b>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="99" style="width:74.3pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">ISIN</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" style="width:80.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">ISIN Location</span></b></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">06/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="60" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:44.65pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">OSEOFI </span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="85" nowrap="" style="width:64.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">1%</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="110" nowrap="" style="width:82.7pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">25/10/2019</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="99" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:74.3pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">FR0011898196 </span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" nowrap="" style="width:80.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">FR</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">07/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="60" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:44.65pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">ESM </span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="85" nowrap="" style="width:64.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">0.875%</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="110" nowrap="" style="width:82.7pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">15/10/2019</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="99" nowrap="" style="width:74.3pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">EU000A1U9829
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" nowrap="" style="width:80.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">DE</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><u><span lang="EN-US"><span style="text-decoration:none">&nbsp;</span></span></u></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><u><span lang="EN-US"><span style="text-decoration:none">&nbsp;</span></span></u></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><b><u><span lang="EN-US">Â£ SUPR:</span></u></b></p>
    <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="606" style="width:454.25pt; margin-left:-1.05pt; border-collapse:collapse">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Available on TW</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="70" style="width:52.15pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Ticker</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="71" style="width:53.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Coupon</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="115" style="width:86.2pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Maturity Date
                        </span></b>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="97" style="width:72.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">ISIN</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="130" style="width:97.3pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">XS ISIN Location</span></b></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">06/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="70" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:52.15pt; border:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">FMSWER </span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="71" nowrap="" style="width:53.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">FRN</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="115" nowrap="" style="width:86.2pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">09/05/2016</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="97" nowrap="" style="width:72.8pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">&nbsp;DE000A11QBT6&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="130" nowrap="" style="width:97.3pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">DE</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><u><span lang="EN-US"><span style="text-decoration:none">&nbsp;</span></span></u></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><b><u><span lang="EN-US" style="color:black">$ SUPR: </span>
        </u></b><b><u><span lang="EN-US"></span></u></b>
    </p>
    <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="823" style="width:617.0pt; margin-left:-1.05pt; border-collapse:collapse">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Available on TW</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="80" style="width:60.2pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Ticker</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="100" style="width:75.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Coupon</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="113" style="width:84.5pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Maturity Date
                        </span></b>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="105" style="width:78.5pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">ISIN</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" style="width:80.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">ISIN Location</span></b></p>
                </td>
                <td width="195" style="width:146.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:black">Benchmark</span></b></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">07/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="80" nowrap="" style="width:60.2pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">MP</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="100" nowrap="" style="width:75.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">3.050</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="113" nowrap="" style="width:84.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">14/05/2024</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="105" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:78.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">US563469UD51 </span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" nowrap="" style="width:80.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">CA</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="195" nowrap="" style="width:146.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">US912828WJ58</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">08/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="80" nowrap="" style="width:60.2pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">IBRD</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="100" nowrap="" style="width:75.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">0.976</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="113" nowrap="" style="width:84.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">09/05/2019</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="105" nowrap="" style="width:78.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">XS1055866559</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" nowrap="" style="width:80.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">XS</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="195" nowrap="" style="width:146.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">3M LIBOR</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">09/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="80" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:60.2pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">AUST
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="100" nowrap="" style="width:75.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">0.000</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="113" nowrap="" style="width:84.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">07/05/2015</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="105" nowrap="" style="width:78.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">XS1066373421</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" nowrap="" style="width:80.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">AT</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="195" nowrap="" style="width:146.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">US912828C814</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt">
                <td width="124" nowrap="" style="width:92.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">09/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="80" nowrap="" style="width:60.2pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">BNG</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="100" nowrap="" style="width:75.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">FRN</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="113" nowrap="" style="width:84.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">15/05/2014</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="105" nowrap="" style="width:78.5pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">XS1068089025</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="107" nowrap="" style="width:80.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">NL</span></p>
                </td>
                <td width="195" nowrap="" style="width:146.0pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">3M LIBOR</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Never used jSoup, but the JavaDoc shows `Elements` has a `size()` method.  I'd start there: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html

Comment: that doesnt work as it returns the number for the whole document opposed to per table body

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  You select a specific table and reference it by `table`, then you use that to get the tbody and call it `tbody`.  Unless this is the weirdest API ever, I would expect each subsequent `select()` call would be limited to only those elements within the DOM element you called it on.  The JavaDoc on `Elements` seems to back this up: "Find matching elements within this element list."

Comment: admitadley i chopped some of the html out of the post but if i were to call `tr.size` i get 13 - now that definately isnt the number of table rows per table body - thats the total number of table rows for the given table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use size method. The `document.select("table[class=MsoNormalTable] tbody")` statment gives all the tbody and and form that if you select tr and check size you'll get the number.

Iterate over each tbody and get tr size like

```
Elements tables = document.select("table[class=MsoNormalTable] tbody");

int index = 0;
for(Element table : tables){
    System.out.println("Table : " + (++index) + " has " + table.select("tr").size() + " rows.");
}
```

Comment: Table : 1 has 13 rows.
Table : 2 has 13 rows.
Table : 3 has 13 rows.
Table : 4 has 13 rows.

Comment: I got it as Table : 1 has 3 rows.
Table : 2 has 2 rows.
Table : 3 has 5 rows. I just copy pasted your xml to an html file and processed it. So in that case i suppose your complete url is returning more rows. Can you share the url or complete html?

Comment: ahhhh you are completely correct - that is a mistake on my part - i missed the `tbody` from `document.select("table[class=MsoNormalTable] tbody"` thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc, the `select()` "Find[s] matching elements within this element list", which indicates the return is limited to the DOM elements under the element(s) you are searching in (like a limit), and the `size()` returns the "size in interface Collection".  This seems to indicate that using `select()` on a given DOM element followed by the `size()` on the returns `Elements` would give you the size/count of all the `Elements` returned by the select.  You are doing a select of all tables that have the class of 'MsoNormal', which from what I can see in your example are 3 tables.  You then get the `tbody`s, followed by the `tr`s, followed by `td`s.  You are essentially getting all tables (at least the ones you are showing), followed by all `tbody`s, followed by all `tr`s, etc, etc.  If you want to limit the count to ONLY the `tr`s in a single table, then you will need to limit the things are are searching in (i.e. the `table`s) to the single table you want to count.

If that is not possible, then get the `List<Element>`s from the `table` select, loop through each one, then use the [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html)s select to limit the search to only that one Element.  It's really just a matter of reading the API and figuring out what you need to do.  Do you want to search on the `Elements` you returned or the `Element`s individually?